# Is there a way to make a custom control component for expo-av video?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-av

I am trying to reproduce on React Native the following player that I made on a wireframe software.

So I have started using the Video component of the expo-av library but I have found no way to control play/pause, as well as the current millis property. 
I think the onPlaybackStatusUpdate prop is here to update an object containing the actual properties relating to playback and I think using a useState is the right approach to access these values for UI purposes but I don't know how to modify these values to play/pause the playback or jump a few seconds forwards or back.

[image: Video interface here]

I'm a little bit lost and I don't really what to do from that point on, I have searched elsewhere for answers on how to control those properties from UI components but so far no luck